# Can I downlaod Ububtu onto a disk

Tags: downloads, cd

I just need to download ubuntu onto a disk. How do i do it? I can't seem to figure it out. I feel funny asking but I need help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking to burn the downloaded iso (what you got when you went to Ubuntu.com and downloaded the Desktop version) onto a disk. [Follow this guide.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) It is instructions for creating a USB installer, but you can follow a link on the side for DVD instructions.

Answer (score 1):

You can download and burn an Ubuntu .ISO onto a DVD or use a USB installer as answered by [iamwpj](https://askubuntu.com/users/107491/iamwpj).

If you wish to burn it to disc then it must be a DVD, as current 700MB CD's will not fit all of the information upon it.

Ubuntu .ISO is 883MB, so it will not fit onto a standard Compact Disc.

Burn the disc at the slowest speed possible to ensure that the image is of excellent quality.

Answer (score 0):

Once downloaded you get an image. It is necessary to burn it on a dvd. Press F2 in order to start your PC by the disc driver. Restart your machine with the dvd. That's all.